# Can I use the function yes () to return 1

Tags: function, lua, helper

Is the following function is correct?

```
local function yes()
return 1
end

local function no()
return 0
end
```

Can I use it to set the values ​​of the variables in this way?

```
local May_I = yes()
if May_I ~= 0 then
-- Yes I can do that
end
```

I like numbers, but sometimes they are not very precise.

Comment: Why not just create global constants for `YES` and `NO` instead? The overhead of a function call here seems excessive. But, yes, I think that would work...you could also use Lua's native TRUE/FALSE depending on your version...

Comment: Why do you *want* to? Are the boolean `true` and `false` just too complex for you?

Comment: yes(), you can use your functions, but standard Lua logic operators `and`, `or`, `not`, `if` will not work with numbers.

Comment: What do you mean *sometimes they are not very precise*?

Comment: @crush If I use your solution - the logical operators had mentioned @ EgorSkriptunoff Skrip will work?

Comment: @NicolBolas I want to make synonyms that will be readable even for someone with less knowledge. variable names will serve as questions and values of variables answers. Are there other ways to achieve this goal?

Comment: @lhf I mean that sometimes I do not understand my own code after some time. Sad to write this but it's true.

Comment: @BrutalApple: "*I want to make synonyms that will be readable even for someone with less knowledge.*" This severely underestimates the intelligence of whomever you intend to use this system. I think people know what `true` and `false` mean.

Comment: @NicolBolas You're right, maybe this way is the worst possible solution, but possible and for me easier to read after some time. What do you think?

Comment: @BrutalApple: Using plain true and false is simpler and is more idiomatic Lua. Its usually better to adapt to the language you are writing instead of trying to force the language into what you are used to.

Answer (score 3):

You can deal with the imprecision you mentioned like so:

```
> epsilon = 1e-2
> function yes()
>>  return 1
>> end
> if math.abs( yes() - 1 ) <= epsilon then
>>  print("Yes I can")
>> end
Yes I can
```

Or alternately, be precise and use `true` and `false`.

Comment: +1 Great way to deal with boolean precision issues